# Twitter threaded reading

Tags: twitter, reading

Reading a full discussion including all sub-threads in Twitter is hard if the discussion fork into many sub-discussions and you want to make sure you have read it all.

So I am looking for a Twitter client that:

- Threads discussion similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nntp.jpg
- Runs on Windows
- Preferably is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Free_Software_Definition)
- May be web app
- Plus if it runs it runs on Android or GNU/Linux

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5269312/1333493 but it seems broken and both https://tinysubversions.com/spooler/ and https://threadreaderapp.com can't handle replies by different users

Comment: It seems Thunderbird's chat view may have some kind of threading feature for Twitter, per https://www.lifewire.com/best-native-twitter-clients-for-linux-4114353